# Installing php5 on Windows

Tags: php, installation

So I am trying to get a php program to work on my server (Windows server 2008 R2), and I have followed a tutorial to install php.

When I enter the address the website loads which means php is installed - but I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\[..]\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177
```

After some googling I found that this is related to mb_string (?), so I went to the php directory to edit the php.ini and uncomment:

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

To my surprise there was only a `php.ini-development` and a `php.ini-production` - so I made a duplicate of `php.ini-production` and renamed it to `php.ini`. I hope that's the way to do it?

After the edit, I saved the file and restarted the webserver from IIS7.
But the problem remained. Also `phpinfo()` didn't list any mb_string.

So my question is: What's the issue here and how can I enable mb_string (if that's needed)?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you edited the right php.ini? Check the `phpinfo()` for correct path

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\Windows -
Loaded Configuration File  C:\php5\php.ini

Comment: Just a hint: Get PHP Manager for IIS. Makes configuring PHP on Windows a lot easier.